# Layout FastReport

Tags: delphi-7, delphi-xe3, fastreport

I am creating a report in Fastreport 5.
How do I put all records of the detail band within a rectangle
without showing the horizontal lines between the items?

In QuickReport it was simple, just configure the properties of the band frame:

```
Frame.DrawTop: = True;
Frame.DrawLeft: = True;
Frame.DrawRight: = True;
Frame.DrawBottom: = True;
```

In this way the band had a contour.
This does not work on FastReport, so I'm drawing the rectangle inside each band, but the detail band does not behave as expected, ie without the lines between the record

Answer (score 0):

A member of Embarcadero named Alan Glei help me with this answer:
You can add a blank text box, enable the Left and Right borders, mark the alignment of the same as client, and send it all back. With this you should have the look you want. Congratulations! It's solved.